# primefaces PieChartModel's Data Display

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to primefaces.When I use PieChartModel then it displays data in percentage.
For instance my data is **labors=4** and **administrator=6** .It will show a pie chart which displays `60%` and `40%` while I want it to display 6 and 4 on the chart.
Is there a way so we can do like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> dataFormat  : Defines data information type on highlighter or slices. Default is percent.

just set the `dataFormat="value"`

like this

```
<p:pieChart dataFormat="value" ...
```

Comment: how can i give their multiple values? like 4 for labors and 6 for admin?

Comment: just like in the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pieChart.jsf set the value to 4 and 6 , `pieModel.set("labors", 4); pieModel.set("administrator", 6);`

Comment: the string `value` like this `dataFormat="value"`

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooook :) got it.Thanks Man :)