# show real value when hover part in pieChart primefaces

Tags: primefaces, hover, default-value, pie-chart

I want to show the value (not percent, but the real value before calculating percentage) of each part of pieChart when I hover each one

here is my pieChart :

```
  <p:pieChart id="mypie" extender="ext" value="#{statistiquesMB.pieModelRegions}" 
                legendPosition="e"  
            showDataLabels="true"  
            seriesColors="FFFFFF, FFFF00, FF00FF, FF0000, C0C0C0, 808080, 808000, 800080, 800000, 00FFFF, 00FF00, 008080, 008000, 0000FF, 000080, 000000"
             style="width:900px;height:500px" sliceMargin="5" diameter="440" />
```

I don't find this option in the user guide of Primefaces.

Answer (score 3):

Primefaces [PieChart](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pieChart.jsf) seems to based on [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/).

On the [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) site there is an [example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) that shows the option: `dataLabels: 'value'`.

So just set this attribute on your `pieChart` component:

```
<p:pieChart 
    id="mypie" 
    dataFormat="value"
    extender="ext" 
    value="#{statistiquesMB.pieModelRegions}" 
    legendPosition="e"  
    showDataLabels="true"  
    seriesColors="FFFFFF, FFFF00, FF00FF, FF0000, C0C0C0, 808080, 808000, 800080, 800000, 00FFFF, 00FF00, 008080, 008000, 0000FF, 000080, 000000"
    style="width:900px;height:500px" sliceMargin="5" diameter="440" />
```

Comment: Just figured: There is already an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12890647/332248) to this.

Comment: thank you for your response but, I want to show the real value when I hover each part of the pieChart, not instead of percentage

Comment: @begiPass am also facing the same problem, were you able to make it work?

Comment: sorry, I havent use this from that time

Comment: @Darth Did you check the other SO answer from my first comment?

Comment: @Jens oh, I haven't seen your comment when I made mine. Not really sure how that slipped on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually with javascript as ska explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31022386/2098871).

They are using Primefaces 5.x, in your case you have to use the tag `extender="pieExtender"` where pieExtender is the javascript function.

Better late than never...