# PrimeFaces Piechart: Tooltips are not displaying in my local environment

Tags: primefaces, charts, tooltip, pie-chart

I have recreated the example page shown in the primefaces showcase at:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/pie.xhtml

The pie chart successfully display and I am able to tweak the pie chart model for available setters and getters, but hovering over a piece of the pie does not display any tooltip at all.

This is not a browser issue, as in the same browser the tooltips display on the demo site.

The jqplot-highlighter-tooltip div is showing in the html source, but it is not getting updated on hover. There are no errors shown in the javascript console.

I am using the 5.2 maven dependancy, and have also tried 4.0 - but with no change.

Would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

The code for the managed bean is as follows:

```
package org.primefaces.examples;

import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1075867144472594293L;

    private PieChartModel pieModel1;
    private PieChartModel pieModel2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        createPieModels();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel1() {
        return pieModel1;
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel2() {
        return pieModel2;
    }

    private void createPieModels() {
        createPieModel1();
        createPieModel2();
    }

    private void createPieModel1() {
        pieModel1 = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel1.set("Brand 1", 540);
        pieModel1.set("Brand 2", 325);
        pieModel1.set("Brand 3", 702);
        pieModel1.set("Brand 4", 421);

        pieModel1.setTitle("Simple Pie");
        pieModel1.setLegendPosition("w");
    }

    private void createPieModel2() {
        pieModel2 = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel2.set("Brand 1", 540);
        pieModel2.set("Brand 2", 325);
        pieModel2.set("Brand 3", 702);
        pieModel2.set("Brand 4", 421);

        pieModel2.setTitle("Custom Pie");
        pieModel2.setLegendPosition("e");
        pieModel2.setFill(false);
        pieModel2.setShowDataLabels(true);
        pieModel2.setDiameter(150);
    }

}
```

The code for the view page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head/>

<h:body>
    <p:chart type="pie" model="#{chartView.pieModel1}" style="width:400px;height:300px" />

    <p:chart type="pie" model="#{chartView.pieModel2}" style="width:400px;height:300px" />
</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the same problem. Using an extender fixed it :

- Facelet :

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function pieExtender() {
          this.cfg.highlighter = {
              show: true,
              tooltipLocation: 'n',
              useAxesFormatters: false,
              formatString: '%s = %d'
          };
      }
  </script>
  ```
- Managed Bean :

  ```
  pieModel.setExtender("pieExtender");
  ```

For more tweaking see : http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html

Comment: I thought it wasn't working in my project because I am using Primefaces 4.0, but with this workaround I got the usefull tooltips. Good job, ska.