# PrimeFaces pieChart customization

Tags: primefaces, pie-chart, jqplot

I am trying to add tooltip to legend of piechart and remove the description from it. Here is a basic demonstration of this(I added explanation to pictures) : 
[image]
In light of this image, I want to accomplish two things:

1-Firstly, I want to remove description from the legend section. As far as I understand, when I set the data source like this, it both sets tooltip of chart and legend label:

```
pie.set(String category, Number data)
```

However, since I am getting description from database, it can be very long and this causes legend to overlap chart like this:
[image]

***So, I only want to show data as tooltip on the chart and legend section(on the labels) and remove description from legend***. Here is the javascript code(s) that I tried:

```
function chartExtender() {

    this.cfg.legend = {
        show: true,
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            useAxesFormatters: false
        },
        tooltipLocation: 'nw',
        placement: 'inside',
        rendererOptions: {//I tried that one and above highlighter respectively.
            highlighter: {
                tooltipFadeSpeed: 'slow',
                tooltipLocation: 'n',
                show: true
            }
        }
    };
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
        show: true,
        useAxesFormatters: false, // must be false for piechart   
        tooltipLocation: 'n',
        formatString: '%s = %d'
    };
}
```

2- Secondly, is there a way to completely customise data sources of legend and chart section? I dont want them bounded like this.

Here is the links I have looked:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846494/customize-primefaces-chart?rq=1  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644676/how-to-use-line-chart-extender-attribute-in-primefaces-5-2
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/pieTest.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889464/jqplot-tooltip-on-bar-chart
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050008/primefaces-3-4-charts-datatipformat
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18445
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32166
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474242/jqplot-pie-chart-tooltips 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224074/primefaces-piechart-tooltips-are-not-displaying-in-my-local-environment
```

Comment: is question not clear? I tried to explain as much as I can with images. I can add additional info if needed.